# Updating the RAM and HDD for my Dell OptiPlex GX280

Tags: hard-drive, dell-optiplex, ddr2

I'm looking to upgrade my [Dell OptiPlex GX280](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/spec_optix_gx280_en.pdf), but can't figure out what type of DDR2 RAM to get, and I also can't seem to figure out if I am supposed to get an SATA, SATA-II, or SATA-III hard drive?

Does anyone know? I have tried looking at the documentation, but can' find what I am looking for.

Comment: Any Sata hard drive will work, avoid the "Advanced Format" hard drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer will take DDR2 RAM running at either 400 MHz (PC3200) or 533 MHz (PC4200). I always use the configurators at [Kingston](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=22234&mfr=Dell&model=OptiPlex%20GX280%20Small%20Form%20Factor&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingston.com&Sys=22234-Dell-OptiPlex%20GX280%20Small%20Form%20Factor&distributor=0&submit1=Search) or [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/support/memory_speeds.aspx) to be sure I buy the right module.

Go run ["System Information for Windows"](http://www.gtopala.com) and look at your current memory speeds. If you are running PC3200, you can decide to replace it all with PC4200, or just add more PC3200 (the PC4200 in this case would slow to PC3200 speeds).